# how to get a pc list that have a service running on each pc?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, powershell-2.0

I m using psexec to auto run from cmd on all PCs on our network to check if certain process is running or not. but i wannt a list with all pc name that has the service running on. how can i do it from powershell?

this is what i m running now. 2 batch files and 1 text file.

get.bat

---

tasklist | findstr pmill.exe >> dc-01\c$\0001.txt

---

run_get.bat

---

psexec @%1 -u administrator -p password -c "C:\get.bat"

---

pclist.txt

---

what i got from this in result are just all pmill.exe , i m wondering if there is anyway that i can output the PC name that has pmill.exe running on?

Hint plz!

Comment: Just FYI, your double-posting tactic is not appreciated. Do all your clients have powershell or is it just your machine? Do you have WMI remoting, powershell remothing or both enabled on the client machines?

Comment: no more double-posting!

Comment: all client have powershell installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all computers have powershell installed with remoting enabled, you can try the script below. It also outputs computers that were not reachable so you can retest them later if you want to. If you don't need it, just remove the content inside the `catch`-block(or all of `try/catch`):

```
$out = @()
Get-Content "pclist.txt" | foreach {
    $pc = $_ 
    try {
        if((Get-Process -Name "pmill" -ComputerName $pc) -ne $null) {
            $out += $_
        }
    } catch { 
        #Unknown error
        $out += "ERROR: $pc was not checked. $_.Message"
    }
}

$out | Set-Content "out.txt"
```

pclist.txt:

```
graimer-pc
pcwithoutprocesscalledpmill
testcomputer
testpc
graimer-pc
```

Out.txt (log):

```
graimer-pc
ERROR: testcomputer is unreachable
ERROR: testpc is unreachable
graimer-pc
```

Comment: I m trying the script you made above, in the pc_list.txt file, i have a very long list contains over 100 PCs, but somehow, the script will skip some of the PCs, do you have any idea why?

Comment: like the out.txt above, it looks like missing [tespc]

Comment: the `out.txt` is only missing `pcwithoutprocesscalledpmill`, and I think the name explains why. `out.txt` only contains names where the process is running or where it catched an error(updated it now to include all exceptions). If some names are not on the list, it's most likely because they didn't have "pmill" running

Comment: do yo have any idea why the service is running on remote PC but not showing on the out.txt ? cuz that is what happening now , 1 of the pc have pmill.exe running but on the out.txt shows as error unreachable.

Comment: if you get "ERROR: pcname  is unreachable" in `out.txt` it's because the script can't connect to the computer. If I remember correctly, this uses WMI remoting to test the computer, so make sure that it is enabled.

Comment: I've updated the script to include the exception message on all errors. Try again and check the last sentence in the error-line with http://sebastienlachance.com/blog/processgetprocesses-common-errors . He seems to have some solutions

Comment: looks like your script just working fine. the problem is on the remote pc. i run [tasklist], the pmill.exe is there, and i run [get-service -name pmill] , it could not find anything.......dont know why, the out.txt shows the pmill is not running on remote pc but its running

Comment: maybe its not running as a service

Comment: my scripts checks for processes just like `tasklist`, so if `tasklist` finds it and the script doesn't, it is a remoting problem. to fix it, check out the link i left in the comment above.

Comment: i run tasklist and get-service locally, and i m sure powershell remoting is enabled. i checked all services , there is no pmill.exe. i guess tasklist gives all appliacations running and get-services is all about service. pmill maybe not one of the services running on the background. can i change your script to use tasklist? like this : if((tasklist | findstr pmill.exe -ComputerName $pc) -ne $null) {

Comment: They are EQUAL. Tasklist returns PROCESSES. My script returns PROCESSES.. Please READ my comments

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what kind of remoting is available:

- If Windows remote management (eg. Services.msc can connect) then just use

  ```
  Get-Service -Name theService -computer TheComputer
  ```

  which will return an object if the service is running with information on that service (like its
  status) or nothing if it isn't installed, so assuming `pclist.txt` is one computer name per line,
  to get a list of computers where the service is running (after replacing `serviceName` with the correct
  name: this is likely to be different to the process name):

  ```
  Get-Content pclist.txt | Where-Object {
    $s = Get-Service -name 'serviceName' -computer $_
    $s -or ($s.Status -eq Running)
  }
  ```
- If WMI is available using `Get-WmiObject win32_service -filter 'name="serviceName"' and the`State`member of the returned object in the`Where-Object` above.
- PowerShell remoting: use `Invoke-Command -ComputerName dev1 -ScriptBlock { Get-Service serviceName }` 
  run the `Get-Service` on the remote machine to return the same object (but with `PSComputerName` 
  property added)