# Check every computer in network if specific service runs

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, network-programming

For a software update, I need to know if a specific service runs on all computers. And if not, I need to start this service on the missing devices.

Is there a possibility to realize this in C# or PowerShell?

Comment: take a look here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849804.aspx

Comment: This is possible using the .NET interface to WMI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a mix of all suggestions here and wrote a powershell script.
Any improvements are much appreciated.

```
$strFilter = "computer"

$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry

$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree" 
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000 

$objSearcher.Filter = "(objectCategory=$strFilter)"

$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()
$counter = 0

foreach ($i in $colResults) 
{
    $objComputer = $i.GetDirectoryEntry()
    if (Test-Connection -Computername $objComputer.Name -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        Get-Service -ComputerName $objComputer.Name -Name 'svcname' | ? { $_.Status -eq 'Stopped' } | Start-Service
    }

    $counter++
    Write-Host "finished " + $counter
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell you'd use the `*-Service` cmdlets. [`Get-Service`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849804.aspx) can query services on remote hosts via its `-ComputerName` parameter. The returned services can then be filtered and piped into [`Start-Service`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849825.aspx):

```
$servers = 'FOO', 'BAR', 'BAZ', ...

Get-Service -ComputerName $servers -Name 'svcname' |
  ? { $_.Status -eq 'Stopped' } |
  Start-Service
```

Answer (score 0):

How to find computers running a particular service has already been answered here:
[how to get a pc list that have a service running on each pc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985368/how-to-get-a-pc-list-that-have-a-service-running-on-each-pc)

you should then be able to run `Start-Service -Name <Service Name>`